# WPF Generic Windows

Tags: wpf, window, generics

I want to make a **reusable WPF Window** suitable for different types T.
I have a designer and a codebehind file.

can I do something like this?

```
/*  Code behind file */
public partial class MyWindows<T> : Window
{}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you want isn't *quite* possible.

**Update:** Before .NET 4.0 (i.e. when this answer was originally written), [XAML support for consuming generic types was very limited](https://web.archive.org/web/20160219214423/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/mikehillberg/archive/2006/10/06/limitedgenericssupportinxaml.aspx); e.g. generics only worked on the root element.  In .NET 4.0, some restrictions were lifted.

In .NET 4.0, you can construct a fully specialized generic type.  So while XAML itself still has no concept of generic types, it *can* refer to specializations of generic types.  (By analogy, XAML can't express the notion `List<>` but it can express the notion `List<int>`).  For full details, see the [MSDN page "Generics in XAML"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/xaml-services/generics).

You can construct instances of specialized generic types with the [`x:TypeArguments` Directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/xaml-services/xtypearguments-directive).  For example, with `x` bound to XAML's namespace, `sys` to the `System` namespace, and `scg` to `System.Collections.Generic`, and your own MyWindows' namespace bound to `my` then:

- `<my:MyWindows x:TypeArguments="x:String">` would construct a `MyWindows<string>` instance.
- `<scg:List x:TypeArguments="sys:Tuple(sys:String,sys:Int32)">` would construct a `List<Tuple<string,int>>`

Using generic types is therefore no longer a problem in XAML!

Alas, you want to *define* a generic type in XAML.  That's not possible.  There are two workarounds here.  Firstly (and based on your comments on another question I think this is what you want) you can simple pass a type as a plain parameter.  If you do this, you lose all the compile-time safety features that generics provide, but often enough those aren't relevant.  Secondly, you can define a normal non-generic class with codebehind in XAML, and simply use a generic base class for code reuse.  That way you get at least some proper generics safety and reuse.

Comment: You are wrong when you say "XAML, for instance, doesn't support generics at all" it does via x:TypeArguments, see http://blogs.windowsclient.net/rob_relyea/archive/2009/06/01/xaml-using-generic-types-in-xaml-2009.aspx

Comment: ...and by the looks of it, this has changed! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee956431%28v=vs.110%29.aspx  I'll update the answer :-).

Comment: @EamonNerbonne Sorry my bad, I just learnt about the generic-XAML restriction. :)  I actually ran into this problem yesterday when I was rolling my own container control that took a generic argument for the child control to be aggregated - I could not define the container control in XAML.  Essentially what Nuno is asking here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/02ca0499-80af-4c56-bb80-f1185a619a9e/creating-generic-wpf-user-control  In the end I wrote my generic container without XAML (lucky control is simple) but the aggregated control is still XAML :)

Comment: @MickyDuncan thanks for the heads up and the constructive comment - I hadn't known about the improvements before today.

Comment: @MickyDuncan - yeah, I've rolled C# WPF controls too.  I don't even think it's all that much harder, it's mostly just unusual and therefore takes a while to figure out.  In retrospect, given the limitations of XAML (not just generics), I wish they'ld have concentrated on making a cleaner C# api and skipped XAML entirely.  The only real advantage it has (significant, admittedly) is that it's conventional, and that's not an intrinsic advantage.

Comment: @EamonNerbonne agreed my friend :)

Answer (score 10):

Shamelessly copied from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/02ca0499-80af-4c56-bb80-f1185a619a9e) (and thus not tested)

```
public class ViewBase<T> : Window, IView where T : class, IViewModel 
{ 
    public virtual T Model 
    { 
        get { return DataContext as T; } 
        set { DataContext = value; } 
    } 
}
```

and XAML

```
<src:ViewBase 
    x:Class="View" 
    x:TypeArguments="src:IViewModel" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:src="clr-namespace:MyNamespace" 
    Height="480" Width="640"> 
... 
</src:ViewBase>
```

Comment: This absolutely works on VS 2010 SP1 and IMO is the proper answer to the question! `xmlns:src` directive is foundamental to allow visual studio to see the namespace. Cool!

Comment: How do I have to define the x:TypeArguments if T can be any class? x:TypeArguments="x:Class" doesn't work.

Comment: what is `IView` and `IViewModel`? VS editor suggests that `IView` is from ASP.NET and `IViewModel` is from external packages from Catel or XLabs. I think none of this was intended in answer. Also, nothing was found for `IViewModel` on MSDN

Comment: Wolfrevo Cats: it is your MVVM, you can definite them as you need, there is no base interface. You can consult PRISM for examples. If you are using WPF then you should really consider using MVVM. But then you need a MVVM framework and PRISM is the best one IMHO.